# How to implement google authentication login using python flask 0.10.1 on python version 3.4.3?

Tags: flask, python-3.4, google-authentication, google-signin, flask-login

I have already implemented it on python 2.7.9 by following [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/python) link .

To make the code work of python 3.4.3, I ran:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

inside my virtual environment.

I also reinstalled the following requirements:

```
Flask 0.10  
Flask-KVSession 0.3.2  
Jinja2 2.6  
Werkzeug 0.8.3  
google-api-python-client 1.1  
httplib2 0.8  
itsdangerous 0.17  
python-gflags 2.0  
simplekv 0.5  
wsgiref 0.1.2
```

Out of which `wsgiref` was not supported on python 3.4.3, so I used `mod_wsgi` instead.

Now, when I run the application, the server gets created successfully, but it gives me the following error on the web-page:

http://postimg.org/image/t9v8j5ev5/

Since it seems like the libraries that I am using are not supported by python3, so, are there any other good links which give an insight on implementation of google authentication using flask on python3?

Comment: What is the traceback for where the error is? The error indicates that a package you are trying to use, or your own code, isn't ported to Python 3 and not converting bytes to string type explicitly as it would need to. Under Python 3, implicit conversions are no longer performed.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Here is a complete screen-shot of the error that I am getting on my web-page:
http://postimg.org/image/c23n7ex89/

Comment: @Python_Enthusiast This isn't a complete traceback.

Comment: It is the bottom of the traceback that contains what you need, not the top. Look at it and work out where in the code the problem is occurring.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton OKay, here it is:
http://postimg.org/image/t9v8j5ev5/

Comment: Ensure you have the latest versions of Flask-KVSession and itsdangerous. Most like the session extension package isn't properly Python 3 compatible or something. All I can suggest.